# Scala traits defining other traits

Tags: scala, traits

I ran into an interesting scenario in Scala.  It seems then I have a **base trait** that defines other traits, the implementation cannot find the **base trait** not matter what.

I created this base trait simple for convenience that I don't need to redefined these traits on every implementation.  Do anyone know why this doesn't work?

```
object Base {
   trait Create
   trait Delete
}

trait BaseTrait {
   trait Create extends Base.Create
   trait Delete extends Base.Delete
}

object Implementation extends BaseTrait 

object Something {
   class SomeClass extends Implementation.Create //The trait is not defined. 
}
```

**Update:**
The question has been cleared up a bit so that its more precise.  The solution as @BrianHsu pointed out is that `trait` cannot be inherited.

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue in a REPL session. Are you sure this is the actual code?

Comment: I copy pasted the code and did not get any errors. I am using scala 2.11.6
I have put the entire source in a single scala file.
The problem should be something not captured in the example.

Comment: Hi @GabrielePetronella, example is updated above

Comment: In the future instead of "doesn't work" please be specific, give us the same information that scalac was kind enough to give you (even if you don't comprehend it).

Comment: @nafg fair enough. my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This block of code is fine:

```
object Base {
  trait Event
  trait Command
}
```

The following block will run into to trouble:

```
trait BaseTrait {
  trait Event extends Event
  trait Command extends Command
}
```

But Scala compiler says it very clearly.

```
test.scala:7: error: illegal cyclic reference involving trait Event
  trait Event extends Event
              ^
test.scala:8: error: illegal cyclic reference involving trait Command
  trait Command extends Command
```

Of course you cannot do this, just like you could not do the following in Java:

```
class HelloWorld extends HelloWorld
```

You have to specify that what you extend is actually Base.Event / Base.Command, so it will only work if you write it as:

```
trait BaseTrait {
  trait Event extends Base.Event
  trait Command extends Base.Command
}
```

Another problem in your code it the last `Something` object, it does not make sense at all:

```
object Something {
  Implementation.Event
  Implementation.Commannd
}
```

So compiler give you a clear error message:

```
test.scala:14: error: value Event is not a member of object Implementation
  Implementation.Event
                 ^
test.scala:15: error: value Commannd is not a member of object Implementation
  Implementation.Commannd
```

It's quite obvious, an trait in Scala is much like `interface` in Java, you should not use it as it is a field.

Comment: Got it. So traits being what they are, can't be inherited by the Implementation object.